# "FileNotFoundException - Could not load file or assembly" from a project's library, even if LoadFrom() is used

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, dll, dynamic-loading

I have a VS2017 project composed by:

```
- Main console application `App.exe`, compiled in .NET Framework 4.6.1
--- (referenced by `App.exe`) Custom dynamic library `LibOne.dll`, compiled in .NET Standard 2.0
----- (referenced by `LibOne.dll`) Another dynamic library `LibTwo.dll`, compiled in .NET Framework 3.5
```

By default, both `LibOne.dll` and `LibTwo.dll` are copied in `App.exe` folder when compiling. Instead, I need to prevent `LibTwo.dll` to be copied, making the program look for it from another path of the system, `C:\Path_To_LibTwo`.

So I've set "Copy Local" and "Specific Version" to FALSE for `LibTwo.dll`, in both App and LibOne projects, now the program throws this error just when I call a method of `LibOne.dll`:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in App.exe
Could not load file or assembly 'LibTwo, Version=12.4.0.61, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

This is legit, but the problem still exists even if:

- `C:\Path_To_LibTwo` (where `LibTwo.dll` is contained) has been added to System's PATH
- I've added this line as first thing of my App:
  `System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(@"C:\Path_To_LibTwo\LibTwo.dll");` (Note: this line correctly returns the LibTwo's assembly, so it is found)

**UPDATE**: I added this to App.config:

```
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="LibTwo" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="null" />
        <codeBase href="file:///C:/Path_To_LibTwo/LibTwo.dll" />
    </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```

And now the error is different:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'LibTwo, Version=12.4.0.61, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. 
The private assembly was located outside the appbase directory. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131041)
```

Comment: Is `LibTwo` a compile-time reference in either `LibOne` or `App`?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean with "compile-time reference", anyway it has been added this way: (1) Right-Click `LibOne` project (2) "Add... Refrence..." (3) Select LibTwo.dll (4) Copy Local = false.

I also tried the same thing but adding it directly to App.exe project.

Comment: Well, you need to remove it from references; otherwise, what would be the point of `dynamic-loading`?

Comment: The code of LibOne calls methods of LibTwo. If I remove it from Refrences, LibOne won't compile.

Comment: If that's meant for dynamic loading, then I believe it would make more sense to call methods of LibTwo via reflection instead of referencing it.

Comment: I suggest that you don't call .net framework code in .Net standard. Because some code in .net framework could not work in .net standard. For more information, you could look at [.Net Framework vs .Net Core vs .Net Standard](http://www.mukeshkumar.net/articles/dotnetcore/dotnet-framework-vs-dotnet-core-vs-dotnet-standard) to know the relationship bewteen them.